# Binding to key press doesn't work in IE8 and older

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have this code on my web page:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        if ($('#title').is(":focus"))
        {
            $("#save_post").focus().click();
            $('div .jqEasyCounterMsg').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
        else if ($('#s').is(":focus"))
        {
            $("#searchAddress").focus().click();
        }
    }
});
```

This works in every single browser except older versions of IE (8 and older). What should I change to get this to work in those versions?

Comment: Would you like to a) show a live example, b) show some HTML, c) explain what doesn't work, d) mention the error IE8 throws?

Comment: I explained what doesn't work pretty simply, when you hit enter, nothing happens. No error. I was hoping someone knew of older versions of IE not supporting this key press. I'm not trying to find issues with MY CODE, I'm trying to find other code to do the same thing. This code is right for what it does, just doesn't work in old IE.

Comment: Are you binding that on DOM ready?

Comment: How come all other bindings work, even not in DOM ready, and this works in every other browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your event handler code within a `$(document).ready(...` block and it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).keypress(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Is this standard practice for all "binding" type things in IE? I don't do this when I bind to button clicks, and they all seem to bind fine. I'll give this a shot though thanks.

Comment: You should always do it, not just in IE. Attaching handlers is always unreliable unless the DOM is ready for JavaScript processing. IE is generally fussier than other browsers (in my experience, anyway).

Comment: It is (or should be) standard practice for binding, period. There are other methods, but they're less reliable and generally messier.

Comment: @slandau Not having your JS bindings inside ready() will most likely result in you trying to bind to elements that do not yet exist. Good for you if you have lucked so much and haven't had to deal with this before, but truth of the matter is that it will happen and it's standard practice to bind elements after document is ready.

Comment: Well this is very good to know. I guess I will be moving all my bindings into document ready tonight :)

Comment: actually, it didn't work just moving it into the DOM. won't even alert on key press